# Is it possible to force a class to be passed by reference or pointer (C++)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm not entirely sure what to search for to see if this has been asked, so hopefully it isn't a duplicate.

Supposed I've written a class in C++. Is it possible, by way of constructors or some other internal (to the class) mechanism, to throw a compiler warning when the class is passed to a function *not* by reference.

The motivation behind this is simply to more forcefully control memory allocations. The class in question has several memory pointers that are allocated during class construction (as well as freed/allocated via various class member functions). The allocations are expensive and I want to warn the developer (well, let's be honest, I want to warn myself) of extraneous data copies. However, there are valid use cases for copying the class in other circumstances (might even be valid use cases for passing by value...though I cannot think of any that are unavoidable).

As an aside, the class *can* be passed by value - the class copy *does* work. However, I do not want it to be invoked unless it *needs* to be. Hence the compiler warning instead of an error.

A contrived example:

```
class doNotSilentCopy {
public:

    doNotSilentCopy(size_t size) {
        mysize = size;
        dummy = (int*)malloc(mysize);
    };
    doNotSilentCopy() : doNotSilentCopy(0) {};

    doNotSilentCopy(const doNotSilentCopy& rhs) {
        this->mysize = rhs.mysize;
        this->dummy = (int*)malloc(this->mysize);
    };

    ~doNotSilentCopy(void) {
        if (dummy) {
            free(dummy);
            dummy = nullptr;
            mysize = 0;
        }
    };

    int get(int index) {
        return *(dummy + index);
    };

private:
    size_t mysize;
    int* dummy;
};

int getDataBad(doNotSilentCopy cls, int index) {
    return cls.get(index);
}

int getDataGood(doNotSilentCopy& cls, int index) {
    return cls.get(index);
}

int main() {
    doNotSilentCopy mycls(10);

    int can_I_warn_about_this = getDataBad(mycls, 5);

    int this_is_acceptable = getDataGood(mycls, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should be handled by code review.  As you've stated, there could be valid use cases for copying having it prevented would be limiting.

Comment: What about adding move semantics to the class?

Comment: Make the copy and move constructors private, then have a function exposed which returns a copy.

Comment: As an aside, you don't pass classes, you pass objects, which are instances of a class.

Comment: @NathanOliver That is a good point, but kind of passes the buck to the reviewer. One human isn't much better than another at catching a nuance like this (IMO).

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I have move semantics in the class for making my circular buffer class more efficient but am not sure how they would apply to this situation to resolve the issue I was facing (unintended copies when pass-by-value is used). This is likely due to my ignorance of move constructors (methods?).

Comment: @vandench - this was the solution I ultimately implemented, with PKramer's answer below being accepted.

Comment: @paxdiablo - touché, each year out of school my language becomes more lax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I was typing this "van dench" gave the short answer.
And what Ted Lyngmo also makes sense.
This is the answer in code if you want to be explicit.

```
class NonCopyableNonMoveable
{
public:
    NonCopyableNonMoveable() = default;
    NonCopyableNonMoveable(NonCopyableNonMoveable&&) = delete;
    NonCopyableNonMoveable& operator=(const NonCopyableNonMoveable&) = delete;
    ~NonCopyableNonMoveable() = default;

    NonCopyableNonMoveable Clone()
    {
        return NonCopyableNonMoveable(*this);
    }

private:
    NonCopyableNonMoveable(const NonCopyableNonMoveable&) = default;
};

void f(NonCopyableNonMoveable c)
{
}

int main()
{
    NonCopyableNonMoveable l;
    // f(l); // <== wont compile
    auto copy_of_l = l.Clone();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He specifically said he wants copying to still work, but produce a warning, not an error.

Comment: I know, but I don't know of any way to do that implicitly. And I found that being explicit usually leads to less bugs too

Comment: This answer provides the best solution to my use case, and I agree with @PKramer that being explicit in removing the copy constructor (via delete or making private) while providing a workaround to still be able to copy the object will result in fewer bugs.

This method also allows for having shallow and deep copy, without having any confusion over which of these is implemented by the copy constructor.

Answer (score 4):

To get an error, you'd delete copy construction and copy assignment. You've said you want to retain them, but discourage their use.

Fortunately, modern C++ has an answer for that as well--the `deprecated` attribute:

```cpp
[[deprecated("Please avoid copying objects of this class")]]
DoNotSilentCopy(DoNotSilentCopy const &foo);

[[deprecated("Please avoid copying objects of this class")]]
DoNotSilentCopy &operator=(DoNotSilentCopy const &);
```

Note, however, that this will result in a warning for *any* copy of the object, not just when it's passed as a parameter.

Visual Studio implemented this starting with VS 2015.

**Reference**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/attributes?view=msvc-160

Comment: This is an effective solution, but I found @PKramer's solution below to be more fitting for my use case. That said, there are some other methods in the class that warrant a warning label, "Danger: Here be dragons", where the `deprecated` tag will be tremendously useful. Thank you.